# Data encryption - Multi region

Tags: spring-boot, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-kms

I am using Spring boot with GCP KMS to encrypt some sensitive data. I am using symmetric encryption to encrypt the data before storing that to GCP cloud storage bucket in us-east-1 region. To emphasize, I am using application level encryption inside Spring boot App, on top of what GCP provides at bucket level.

Following a similar Java code mentioned here -
https://cloud.google.com/kms/docs/encrypt-decrypt#kms-encrypt-symmetric-java

We are now working on setting up a DR environment in us-central and want all the data in GCP bucket to be available in DR environment. Based on documentation, GCP buckets can be multi regional, so that's not a problem, and GCP will copy my encrypted data to us-central region.

My challenge is the KMS key. I read that KMS keys are not multi-regional..so  my understanding is that the key I am using in us-east is not available in us-central. So, in case of actual disaster in us-east, my spring boot app wont be able to decrypt my data in us-central region, because key that was used to encrypt data was from us-east, and this same key is no longer available in us-central region of GCP KMS.

How to handle this type of scenario with Google cloud? Do I need to use my own AES key in this case and import that to GCP KMS for encryption/decryption?

Comment: First, you mention KMS, then you mention GCP provided keys. Why did you provide a link to asymmetric encryption? Before implementing a data protection strategy, make sure you know what you are doing. Small mistakes can be fatal.  Edit your post to clearly state what you configured and the problem with error messages. Tip: you misunderstand what multi-regional buckets mean.

Comment: @JohnHanley I edited the question and took asymmetric encryption scenario off. my understanding of multi-region bucket is that.. whatever I write in my bucket in us-east will also be copied to corresponding bucket in other region.  Please correct me if I misunderstood this concept.

Comment: Your edit did not provide the details required. What have you implemented and what is the error? If you have not gotten that far, post once you do. I recommend that you let GCP manage object encryption. As I mentioned, small mistakes are fatal. Encryption, data protection, etc are not something that you learn as you go.

Comment: I can let GCP manage Object encryption.. but the code sample from above link begins with this

String projectId = "your-project-id";
    String locationId = "us-east1";
    String keyRingId = "my-key-ring";
    String keyId = "my-key";

When I run this code in us-central, region will change.. despite that, will GCP KMS going to provide me same values for encryption key when I run the code in a different region? 

This is not an implementation run time error, but part of initial research.

Comment: I do not recommend using learning samples to implement encryption or data privacy/protection. Those examples are very elementary. When you initialize a client, you can specify the project, region, etc, and then run the code in any region, your desktop, or another cloud. Review the SDK documentation for details on each service.